# How to achieve centred box in xaml responsive grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, xamarin

I would like to place a box in the centre of the screen in a XAML Grid Layout. However, I would like to be able to use the grid to place objects inside the box also. See below. How would I do this? If the red box would span 5 rows, of different height, but then the row above and below it must be the same height. There would be a similar arrangement for the columns. It must be responsive, such that the code works on a wide range of device sizes. I am using xamarin.
 [image: EG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Xamarin introduces any different behavior, but with vanilla XAML, you should be able to set `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center` and the box should be centered (you need to provide an explizit size or put something into the box).

If you want to layout content in the box, you should define a separate `GridLayout` inside the box (maybe taking a look at `SharedSizeGroup` if you need to share sizes between the two grids).

Comment: OK, thanks. How would I define the box then and what layout would it sit in?

Comment: That really depends on how it should look like in the end. Probably something like: <GridLayout>...<Box><GridLayout>...</GridLayout></GridLayout>.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.Views.Welcome"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600" Background="Beige">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="400" Width="200" Background="BlanchedAlmond">
    <Grid Height="200" Width="100" Background="Chartreuse"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```